# Blender 2.49b opens with all tools and menus super small - how to fix?

Tags: interface

I am using version 2.49b because my work requires it. I changed the font using "User Preferences" but that only changed the top menu. Any help is appreciated! I am new to Blender.
[image: Using version 2.49b since my work requires it]

Comment: What is your monitor resolution? this may be a display scaling issue.

Comment: What kind of work has such a limiting requirement?

Comment: @MartinZ - [niftools](http://niftools.sourceforge.net/wiki/Blender), for example

Comment: @metaphor_set, I realize one can use other obsolete software that comes from 10 years ago with it, I was just wondering what actual job would require that. Sounds like a situation to look for alternative workflows that may exist. The question itself is a tough one, I would imagine few people are familiar enough with versions this old to troubleshoot problems like this.

Comment: The problem is clearly scaling on 4K monitor. I think there are some DPI compatibility options provided with Windows that might work if you right-click the shortcut or executable and chose Properties and go to Comparability tab. I doubt that UI scaling was a thing when 2.49 was released and I would be surprised if there was a solution inside Blender...

Comment: @MartinZ - Blender isn't "corporate" enough to refuse answers to old versions that might still be useful to some of us.

Comment: No, it is not. If a solution is possible, I see nothing wrong with a question like this. However I see no reason to forget the bigger picture - 2.49 version is very outdated. I think in any case it is necessary to use it it is also worth to look for alternatives in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Go to "Panels - View all" or press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key on your keyboard. This  should align the panels according to the size of your Buttons window.

[image: "Viel all" location]

If you want to resize the panels manually, you can do this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use your Mouse Wheel to adjust the size.

[image: use ctrl + mouse wheel to adjust the size]

Answer (score 1):

My "fix" turned out to be: pressing ctrl and dragging my window larger, and going to "User Preferences" -> Language & Font -> Font size: 16. I have to do this every time I open Blender - it doesn't seem to be saving my preferences.
Thanks for all the replies!